# How to solve the Qgis error when try to import a plugin created in lower version than 2.0?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 219, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/Drisya/.qgis2/python/plugins\iWrm\__init__.py", line 36, in classFactory
    from iWrm import iWrmPlugin
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Drisya/.qgis2/python/plugins\iWrm\iWrm.py", line 40, in 
    import doSoilErosion, doWaterDemandDom, doWaterDemandAgri, doWaterDemandInd, doWaterDemandLstock, doWaterDemandTotal, \
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\Drisya\.qgis2\python\plugins\iWrm\tools\doSoilErosion.py", line 12, in 
    import GdalToolsUtils as Utils
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 478, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\Drisya\.qgis2\python\plugins\iWrm\tools\GdalToolsUtils.py", line 207, in 
    class FileDialog:
  File "C:\Users\Drisya\.qgis2\python\plugins\iWrm\tools\GdalToolsUtils.py", line 209, in FileDialog
    def getDialog(self, parent = None, caption = QString(), acceptMode = QFileDialog.AcceptOpen, fileMode = QFileDialog.ExistingFile, filter = QString(), selectedFilter = None, useEncoding = False):
NameError: name 'QString' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

< 2.0 plugins can't run in > 2.0 unless they are upgraded.  QGIS went though a API change and plugins need to change too.

Here is a guide on how to convert older plugins:

https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20

Comment: i am trying to learn from the same for the past two days. I am in doubt in using Qstring. how to convert the caption= Qstring and filter=Qstring appropriately in a code?

Comment: `caption='', filter=''` or `caption=None, filter=None`

Comment: ....thank you for your advice. I made the coorections appropriately...But, nothing is displayed in thr plugin when trying to access from qgis environment. No error is reporting and the plugin display colour has changed from red to normal.(i.e no error in the paths)..May i know why the plugin shows this type of display error and how to rectify it.